# Обновление версии Erlang

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elementary-os

я пользуюсь Elementary OS Freya (на базе Ubuntu 14.04) и у меня, что бы я не делал, всегда устанавливается Erlang/OTP 17, я и с [erlang-solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) качал .deb пакет версии 18.3 и `sudo apt-get install erlang`
 судя по выводу устанавливает версию 18.2, но `erl -v` продолжает упорно выдавать Erlang/OTP 17, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Удалось решить проблему только с помощью менеджера версий [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf).

Answer (score 1):

В качестве простого и удобного менеджера версий для erlang могу посоветовать kerl. В нём можно в несколько команд билдить и устанавливать любые версии erlang и в любое время быстро переключаться между ними. Плюс хорошо задокументирован.

[github.com/kerl/kerl](http://github.com/kerl/kerl)